# Is there a design pattern for scheduling an "event" to happen in the future?

Tags: python, design-patterns, web-applications, scheduled-tasks

I'm working on a web application that sends users a text message when a certain event occurs. The basic conditions look like this:

1. The event occurs more than once, but not at a reasonably predictable frequency.
2. At any time I can predict if the event will or will not occur within the next 10 days
3. *If* the event is occurring within that time period, I can predict when the event will occur within 1 second.

I'd like to send the text message to the user just before (~5 minutes) the event occurs.

What's the best way to "schedule" a method call (to send the text) for sometime in the future?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the environment. At a first glance I think **cron** is what you're looking for; make a crontab entry on your server that calls a script every minute, and then this script should look for a certain flag (in a file, in database, wherever you see fit) to see if there's something to send.

Basically, you'll need a queue (for multiple users) and a timed php script.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 0):

use a cronjob that just runs once a minute and looks for any events within 6 minutes that havent been notified

or use a command like

```
future_pattern = "%M %H %d %m ? %Y"
command = 'python do_something.py'
evt_tim = datetime.datetime(2013,8,22,14,22) # aug 22,2013 @ 2:22pm
notify_time = evt_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
subprocess.call("%s  %s"%(notify_time.strftime(future_pattern),command)
```

or use a service thats made for this like twillio
http://blog.iron.io/2012/10/how-to-schedule-sms-and-calls-on-twilio.html

Answer (score 0):

In JAVA I would recommend [QUARTZ](http://quartz-scheduler.org/). IS is easy co configure and it supports persistence.